# MAX function... use Max function for column name from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

Im not sure if I can do something like that:

In the select statement I used the following statement:

```
case when table1.EffectiveDate > table1.IssueDate then  table1.EffectiveDate else table1.IssueDate end as Result
```

It works and it displays Result column

But then I also want to display MAX (Result)

How can I do it?

```
SELECT
case when table1.EffectiveDate > table1.IssueDate then  table1.EffectiveDate else table1.IssueDate end as Result

FROM …

Where  …

Group By….
```

Answer (score 0):

You have almost mentioned the answer in your question

```
 SELECT 
 max(
 case when table1.EffectiveDate > table1.IssueDate 
     then table1.EffectiveDate 
 else table1.IssueDate end
 ) as Result

 FROM …

 Where …
```

If you still want to get both of them:
Select Result, max(Result) from(

```
SELECT 
case when table1.EffectiveDate > table1.IssueDate 
then table1.EffectiveDate 
else table1.IssueDate end
as Result

FROM …

Where …)

Group by Result
```

Comment: Lesya, I need Result column and from the Result column I would like to get MAX result. I would like to to something like MAX(Result). I already created result column base on case when table1.EffectiveDate > table1.IssueDate then table1.EffectiveDate else table1.IssueDate end as Result. Now I would like to display MAX(Result).

Comment: Ok. But then based on which criteria the single max() result and the list of values in Result must be joined? Or, must max() appear as a resulting row?

Comment: So I created Result column (it contains dates) now I would like to display max date. MAX Date means the latest date. I cant just use MAX (Result) in select statement after the case when table1.EffectiveDate > table1.IssueDate then table1.EffectiveDate else table1.IssueDate end as Result

Comment: Max(Result) returns a single value, while Result returns one column. If you willuse them as select max(Result), Result ....group by Result, you will get a list of non-duplicate equal values in both columns. But,if this is something you need, I have editted the query.

Comment: I'd like to return a single value from the Result table: the latest date. It doesn't work for me. Result column is a just column which I crated in the select statement. I don't have this column in any table in database. Maybe because of that i couldn't use MAX function? It doesn't recognize MAX(Result). It says invalid column name.

Comment: If you mean, you wish to write max(Result) in some other place:query/function/procedure-no, it won't work. You have to store it somewhere.